# How to send an id to a get method

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to get a snapshot of a news id through ActivatedRoute so I can later pass that id to a method in a service which asks for that particular news id through an api route.

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiNoticiasService } from './api-noticias.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-editar-noticias',
  templateUrl: 'editar-noticias.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['editar-noticias.component.css'],
  providers: [ApiNoticiasService]
})
export class EditarNoticiasComponent implements OnInit {
  noticia: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _apiNoticias: ApiNoticiasService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._apiNoticias.getNoticia(this.route.snapshot.params.id)
      .then( (noticia) => this.noticia = noticia)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

}
```

And this is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ApiNoticiasService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getNoticia(id) {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/noticia/:id')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .toPromise()
      .catch((err: any) => {
        console.log(err); 
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
  }

}
```

Sadly, I get this error in my component from ts: Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.route.snapshot.params['id']` this way you get id from `snapshot`.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._apiNoticias.getNoticia(+this.route.snapshot.params['id'])  //<---this way you get id. + sign will convert it to number.
      .then( (noticia) => this.noticia = noticia)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}
```

---

```
getNoticia(id:number) {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/noticia/:'+ id)   //<----changed it.
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .toPromise()
      .catch((err: any) => {
        console.log(err); 
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
}
```